# spring web-mvc 4 java config doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-java-config, tomcat8

I'm trying to run elementary spring-4 web-mvc application without xml configuration at all. I've looked spring documentation and examples, but it didn't work for me. 
My controller:

```
package com.nikolay.exam.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String home() {
    return "Hello world!";
}
}
```

AppConfig:

```
package com.nikolay.exam.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
}
```

WebConfig:

```
package com.nikolay.exam.config;
import com.nikolay.exam.controller.HomeController;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public HomeController homeController() {
        return new HomeController();
    }
}
```

And WebInitializer:

```
package com.nikolay.exam.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        root.setConfigLocation("com.nikolay.exam.config");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(root));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");

    }
}
```

But when I run my application on tomcat I receive an error:

> 14-Feb-2015 11:35:29.825 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/home/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
>   14-Feb-2015 11:35:32.766 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/nikolay/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/manager
>   14-Feb-2015 11:35:32.904 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /home/nikolay/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/manager has finished in 136 ms
>   14-Feb-2015 11:35:34.888 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/home/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the way you register your config class that is not correct.

Try using the [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext#register](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html#register-java.lang.Class...-) instead.

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
appContext.register(WebConfig.class);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is the same issue. 14-Feb-2015 13:26:14.631 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/home/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
14-Feb-2015 13:26:17.570 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /home/nikolay/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/webapps/manager

Comment: The issue with the context mapping. If I change RequestMapping(value = "/home" ..)  to the "/" it works correctly. But why it didn't work with "/home"?

Comment: @Nikolas Sorry to get back to you so late, but from what I see, you're trying to reach `/home/` and not `/home` (without the trailing `/`).  


The `/` is important and it represents two different URL

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to change

```
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```

to

```
dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```