# spring WARNING: Request method 'HEAD' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I receive warning message per second after successful deployment on tomcat 7:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound
>   handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported WARNING: Request method 'HEAD' not
>   supported

but [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514839/spring-web-mvc-4-java-config-doesnt-work) works. How to avoid this annoying message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug of IntelliJ IDEA

[**>> see issue**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135196#comment=27-909624)

it will be fix in next release and until that there is a patch was created by them [Download link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/javaee-impl.jar?file=74-212150&v=0&c=true)

Close idea and Replace bellow file with downloaded one(before do that keep backup of the original file)

`<idea home>/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-impl.jar`

Answer (score 9):

You would need to add the following `@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})` on your methods which are failing. This will allow them to handle `HEAD` requests and should make the warning go away.